# Storing One String Value in an empty LinkedList

Tags: java, string, memory, linked-list, storage

```
public class LinkedListExplained {


public Node head;
public Node tail;

public int size;

public LinkedListExplained() { // Constructor
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
}

public class Node{ // Inner Class
    String value;
    Node next;
}

public void add(String value){
    Node node = new Node();
    node.value = value;

    size++;
    if (head == null){
        head = node;
        tail = node;
        return;
    }
    tail.next = node;
    tail = node;

}
```

Question, when storing a single String value to an empty LinkedList, does it store the same value twice?
Once as head and once as tail?

Comment: How many times is `value` assigned to a node's member? If you can answer that, then there's your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are learning Java, the first and foremost thing you need to understand is that in Java, everything that looks like an object is never actually an object; it is a pointer to an object.  And of course two pointers may point to the same object.

So, the statement `public Node head;` does not declare an instance of `Node`. It declares a pointer to an instance of `Node`. That's why you have to use `new Node();` later.

So, since you set both the `head` and the `tail` pointers to point to the same instance of `Node`, it might appear that you have two copies of that node, but in fact you do not. You only have one instance of `Node`, and you have two pointers pointing at it.

Answer (score 2):

No. The `head` and `tail` variables point to the same `Node` object. That object contains the `String` once.